# how to test a string that contains only letter characters and dash(-) [javascript]

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to create a regex for a word that contains only letter characters and the dash symbol (-). It can not be repeated in succession (e.g. --). Here's my regex function:

```
var regex = new RegExp(/(\w*\-{0,1})*/);
```

This function should work for a word like: `home-do`g or even something like, `home-dog-bird` but not for something like `home--dog`. How can I test this?

Comment: Can you give an example of the text as your question is hard to understand.

Comment: The simplest is `/^\w+(?:-\w+)*$/` or - to allow trailing/leading hyphens - `/^-?\w+(?:-\w+)*-?$/`

Comment: Is a single `-` valid? What about empty words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think about it the other way around (going backwards rather than forwards), you could make a regex that asserts that each match begins with one or more word characters and is followed by zero or more single dash, word pairs

https://regex101.com/r/xT7aT5/2

```
/^\w+(-\w+)*$/
```

Not sure if this is the best approach though.  I like Py.'s answer best atm.

Comment: this works for line broken words, but not in a block of text.  changing the * to a +, you can remove the ^ and $.  https://regex101.com/r/hU0xH7/1

Comment: @MarkEvaul Thanks for the comment.  `^` and `$` are there so I can more conveniently test this using the `m` flag.  It's just so I can have a new-line delimited list of test cases in regex101.  In production, if you are trying to run this against a block of text, yes you would want to remove them.

Comment: right, but if you remove the ^ and $ without changing anything else, then you get false positives of words without - at all.  In other words, you might think this was right based on the test site, but when you move it to prod and remove the ^ and $ to find in a block of text, you'd have a bug you'd have to track down.

Comment: @MarkEvaul hm... I'm probably reading into this too much then.  I see `word-word` convention as a slug.  There's no reason to do that, but being more involved with web development than any other form of programming, I tend to see things through "web eyes".  That being the case, I assumed this was a test against a slug which would mean that single words would be valid.  I read "word that contains only letter characters and the dash symbol" and (probably incorrectly) assumed no dashes is valid too

Comment: true, i guess it is up to the op, as it wasn't very clear in the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that using negative look ahead.

```
var regex=new RegExp(/^(\w|-(?!-))+$/);
```

What this does is matching something that contains only alphanumeric characters and `-` only if it's not followed by another `-`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions for more details on what's possible with the javascript regular expressions.

Comment: Quick [regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/eR6uY0/1) if anyone wants to play with the results.

Answer (score 0):

Another one without lookahead:

```
/^(-?\w+)*-?$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which looks for word and optional for a single dash and words.

```js
function match(s) {
    return !!s.match(/^\w+(\-\w+)*$/g);
}

document.write(match('dog') + '<br>');
document.write(match('dog-cat') + '<br>');
document.write(match('dog-cat-fish') + '<br>');
document.write(match('dog-cat--fish') + '<br>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this:

```
var regex = new RegExp(/^(\w*(\-\w)\w*)*$/);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will match in a body of text.

```
/\w+(-\w+)+/
```

https://regex101.com/r/hU0xH7/1

Answer (score -1):

Try this regex
`/^([^-]*-{0,1}[^-]*)$/`

Comment: This does not match `home-dog-bird`.

Comment: You did not have that requirement in your original question

Comment: First, it's not my question. Second, `home-dog-bird` is a requirement since first revision of the question.

Comment: Sorry , I didn't see the username. And I replied before the OP made his first revision

Comment: The first revision in fact is the original question. You can look at the history to see the original requirements.